# Can I drill access holes so that I can change a front load washer door seal without unstacking dryer

Tags: washing-machine, maintenance, washer

I have a GE front-load washer (wcvh6800j1ww) with a dryer mounted on top. I need to change the door seal, and the default instructions (linked below) involve removing the top and control panel in order to access two screws on the door panel. The washer and dryer are stacked in a location that makes it *extremely difficult* to unstack, specifically, disconnecting and reconnecting the dryer vent without causing damage to drywall and flooring.

If you watch the below video, it looks like the two screws in the top corners of the door panel are the only reason you need to remove the control panel and top. I'm wondering, would it be possible to drill two small access holes in the panel that covers them, so that I can get to those screws? Or does it look like it the door panel needs to be lifted in a way that the control panel needs to be removed either way?

https://youtu.be/7J3RqONy4pw?t=138

Aesthetically I'm not too concerned about the holes since I could easily plug them with screw hole covers painted to match the enamel, but obviously I don't want to do it unless I'm pretty confident it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you will need to drill in the exact places for both screws.

Note that the screws shown in the video were where they ended up - it is most likely that they are positioned elsewhere in your machine ie to the left or right on that diameter.

Then you have to move the clip away…

Once the new seal is fitted then you have to get the clip back on.

And then do up the screws…

All this through two small holes? Don’t fancy your chances unless you are a keyhole surgeon :)

Comment: They're in the same spot. I've taken mine apart before (prior to stacking).

I'm not sure what you're referring to with the other stuff (do you mean the clip around the seal?). Once the door panel is off I have access to everything else.

My main concern is if the panel itself must be lifted significantly to remove it.